# Evaluating false for user defined type guards in classes

Tags: typescript

I have the following Typescript in a [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=7&pretty=true#code/MYGwhgzhAEBiD29oG8BQ0PQA4FcBGIAlsNAOYCmALtJeRJQBQCU0AXNPQE6EB2pAPjxwBbPOU5pMU6Jyo5OPaACIAZoiXpMAX1SaMuAsQwALSAGVK3PszY1jhGA5Q06lVl16loWydIyzKeUVKAE8scngVOwcAOlp6aABeZOUPPiUAbj1vXR1UYHgeBLUkROgecgB3OERmLNRCFQYAQhKY0wgLK1JmFl8MAqL4EHIYkHgetvjqAFpoAEYABiYsvMaGUPDI6CnXJLKlIVFxJT7swYhh0fHJxDi9uaWV1C0gA).

Here is the code:

```
class Foo {
    public get test() : string|number{
        return "foo"
    }

    public  hasString() : this is { test:string }{
        return typeof this.test === "string";
    }

}

const foo = new Foo();

if(!foo.hasString()) {
    console.log(foo.test - 10); // <-- this is an error
}

if(typeof foo.test == "number") {
    console.log(foo.test - 10);
}
```

As far as I understand, when `hasString()` is false, the only other value it can be is `number`. However, typescript still gives an error:

> The left-hand side of an arithmetic operation must be of type 'any',
> 'number', 'bigint' or an enum type.

Why isn't the typescript compiler smart enough to realize if not string, then it must be a number.

Comment: User defined type guards work narrow their arguments (or `this`) either by filtering union members from their types, or by intersecting their type with something else.  `this` is `Foo` which is not a union, so it can't do that.  Instead it would have to intersect; for the `true` case this is `Foo & {test: string}`, but for the `false` case there is nothing it can do... TypeScript lacks *negated types* so here is no `Foo & not {test: string}` for it to produce. ...

Comment: ... It doesn't try to synthesize such a type either.  Contrast this with `if typeof foo.test ===` which is guarding `foo.test` and not `foo`. Unions don't automatically propagate up or down from or to properties.  If this explanation fully addresses your question, I could write it up as an answer with some documentation links.  If not, what's missing?

Comment: That was my wild guess as well. Because if done as a static function, it does work. So is the only solution to do `hasString()` and `hasNumber()`?

Comment: So, should I write up an answer or not?  The question as asked wasn't looking for alternatives; if I'm looking into alternatives I'd need to know more about use cases, since I'd say "just use `if (typeof foo.test === "string") {}`"... but apparently that's not acceptable since you know that works and you're still looking for solutions.  But in any case that looks like you're expanding the scope of the question from "why is this happening".  What would you like to see here?

Comment: I am asking for work arounds and best practices. If the best solution with the current limitation is to do `typeof` then that works for me.

Comment: In your comment you are asking for workarounds and best practices.  In your question post you're only asking why it's happening.  If your primary question is to find an approach that works, then you might want to [edit] the question to make it obvious that this is your focus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use [user-defined type guards](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates) to [narrow](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html) the type of a non-[union typed](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) object in the `false` case.  The main problem with the `false` case of a type guard in general is that TypeScript doesn't support arbitrary *negated types* of the sort implemented (but never merged) in [microsoft/TypeScript#29137](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/29317) where `not X` would match all and only values that are *not* of type `X`.

If you have a union type like `A | B | C | D`, then it's easy to say that a certain type guard should "split" that type into something like `A | B` for a successful test or to `C | D` for a failed test.  After all, if you have a value of type `A | B | C | D` and you know that it *isn't* `A | B`, then it *must be* `C | D`.  But if you have a non-union type then there's nothing to split.  If you have a value of type `X` and you know that it *is* a `Y`, then you can narrow it to the [intersection](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types) `X & Y`.  But if it *isn't* a `Y`, there's no type like `X & not Y` you can narrow it to; the best the compiler can do is leave it as `X`.  Type guards of non-union typed objects are therefore essentially asymmetric.

By making `hasString()` a type guard on `this`, the compiler can narrow a value from `Foo` to `Foo & {test: string}` in the `true` case.  But in the `false` case there's no `Foo & not {test: string}` to narrow to.  The compiler leaves it as `Foo`.

You can read more about this situation in [microsoft/TypeScript#36687](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/36887)

---

If `Foo` were equivalent to `{test: string} | {test: number}`, then the type guard would behave as desired.  But the type checker does not see `{test: string | number}` as equivalent to that type.  In general it would be prohibitively expensive for the compiler to propagate unions up out of properties; see [microsoft/TypeScript#12052](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12052) for more information.

You *could* try to refactor `Foo` to be this way, but `class` declarations cannot produce union types, and so you'd need to do something else, maybe like this:

```
interface FooBase {
  test: string | number;
  hasString(): this is FooString
}
interface FooString extends FooBase {
  test: string;
}
interface FooNumber extends FooBase {
  test: number;
}
type Foo = FooString | FooNumber;
const fooMaker = () => ({
  get test(): string | number {
    return "foo"
  },

  hasString() {
    return typeof this.test === "string";
  }

}) as Foo;

const foo = fooMaker();

if (!foo.hasString()) {
  console.log(foo.test - 10); // <-- okay
}
```

That works, but is yucky.

---

Your example code only seems to care about the `test` property. If so, you might want to just do a type guard on the `test` property itself instead of on `foo`. `Foo` might not be a union, but the `test` property is one.  And we know the compiler can filter those even in the `false` case.  Indeed, this is what you did in your example:

```
class Foo {
  public get test(): string | number {
    return "foo"
  }
}

const foo = new Foo();

if (typeof foo.test !== "string") {
  console.log(foo.test - 10); // <-- okay
}
```

If you really want a user-defined type guard for this you could write one:

```
const isString = (x: any): x is string =>
  typeof x === "string";

if (!isString(foo.test)) {
  console.log(foo.test - 10); // <-- okay
}
```

but it's hardly necessary because [`typeof` already acts as a type guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#typeof-type-guards).

---

So, my suggestion is just to do the `typeof` check directly on the `test` property, until and unless negated types are ever introduced in the language, so that it can reason better about `Foo`s that are not `{test: strings}`s.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-bpHLjw+Yna0jA3jO2OghzZOsRaegCE61TxK0RwjrCtZwuVxudwEG2Gz3enyQAHol0gADyPZ70B0gEq0n6dygAuEATQgMAzHC4vINI9Ekhkcl9aI0pLL2ND+wzdgc2fcnkrTtxQCMcbWbCZpkpDsFiWPV83uTYe22MtDm-JAx3OS5rluBC51eD52mXVcNy3Hc92+EDTmURJjUNdQ2V0EBgBKUk2SQZJ3waN1UTgyo2OLFo0wrGDexotNp3oWdME0YdUQwidsIkqSnnwxcV3XTckG3Xd9wPEgciAA)

Comment: Really well said. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In order for Typescript to narrow a type in an `else` statement, the type needs to be a Union type. Since `Foo` is not of a Union type, Typescript has no type available to narrow `foo` to.

There is a related issue in the TS repo https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/36887

To leverage typeguards in your usecase you can either check just the property type as it is a `string | number` union, or model `Foo` using Union types.

Comment: How do I model `Foo using Union types`? Do you mean `Foo = {test: string} | {test:number}`?